# unexpected 500 errors and networks errors

Tags: contacts, contributions, import, 500

We have a standalone install of CiviCRM Spark, version 5.16.beta1. This is hosted with civicrm.org.  We have imported our contacts, which total about three or four hundred. We are, however, unable to use some of the functions of the site and don't know why. Hoping someone would be able to assist?

When we go into a member record, to update their contributions, we can get as far as clicking "Contributions" in the left hand menu, but the page comes up blank, and there is an error in the top right saying "Network Error
Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again." This error comes up consistently every time. The same thing happens when we click "Memberships" or "Events" in the left hand menu, though the other menu entries seem to work as expected when clicked.

Additionally, when we click "Contributions > Dashboard" in the top-of-screen toolbar menu, we consistently get a 500 error. We also get a 500 error every time we click "Contributions > New Contribution".

Rather weirdly, we also get a 500 error the very first time we visit the CiviCRM home page, however we do not get this 500 error again, it only comes up the first time.

We have also noticed that the public facing page for site visitors to enter their details to become a member, this page is now showing a 500 error as well, meaning no-one can actually sign up at the moment.

As I said above, these problems seem to have manifested since we imported contact data into CiviCRM, which we did using the "Import Contacts" wizard within CiviCRM.

We are not particularly literate when it comes to this kind of configuration, and would appreciate any insight you might be able to provide.

Comment: Enabled the CivicRM debug and backtrace functionality by visiting 'Administer' -> 'System Setting' -> 'Debugging and Error Handling' through navigation menu.
Then check any error message printed on screen.

Check the CiviCRM log file If you have access to it.

Comment: Hi @SunilPawar, thanks, but when visiting Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling we don't see anything looking like an error message at all.  

We see a green section at the top of the page telling us about civicrm.settings.php however as this config file is held on the server, which I believe we don't have access to, since it is hosted at civicrm.org, I don't think we can edit that file anyway.

Comment: As an additional aside, we visited Administer > System Settings > Cleanup caches and update paths but were faced with what looks like a 404 page. The page has a yellow background and reads: 

`Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
QuickForm Error: nonexistent html element
Return to home page.`